# Tool to visualize tree structure similar to filesystem

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have a tree data structure, which resembles a file system. I represent it as a list of tuple `(parent, name, size)` where parent and name are unique strings (actually what is unique the the pair (`parent`, `name`) and `size` is a numerical value which can be think as the size of a folder or a file. Example:

```
('/', 'directory1', 10),
('/', 'directory2', 20),
('/directory2', 'a', 5),
('/directory2', 'b', 15),
```

There are many good tools to visualize the size of directories, with nice UI (example: https://apps.gnome.org/Baobab/). In my case, my structure is not coming from a file-system, even if the structure is very similar. Do you know any good python libraries that help me to visualize the size of the folders?

Comment: For visualization, do you have something in mind like shown by the program TreeSize: https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free

Comment: @jmizv yes (or the link I put)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search, I found that what I need is a "treemap". After knowing that I found several libraries. Here for example an implementation with plotly.

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ('/', 'directory1', 10),
        ('/', 'directory2', 20),
        ('/directory2', 'a', 5),
        ('/directory2', 'b', 15),
    ],
    columns=["parent", "name", "size"],
)

test_df["full_name"] = test_df["parent"].str.rstrip("/") + "/" + test_df["name"].str.rstrip("/")

fig = px.treemap(
    ids=test_df["full_name"],
    parents=test_df["parent"],
    values=test_df["size"],
    names=test_df["name"],
    color_continuous_scale="RdBu",
    branchvalues="total",
)
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
fig.show()
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/wiso/pen/vYPgPLX)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert these structures to RDF triples and save them to Turtle format (Turtle:  Terse RDF 1.1. Triple Language , = textfiles ending  in `.ttl`). Then various tools and libraries, e.g. [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) exist to read in these .ttl files and parse them as a graph, then visualize them e.g. with [rdf2dot](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/main/rdflib/tools/rdfs2dot.py).

On Stackoverflow you'll find some related questions and answers on how to plot such RDF graphs.

If you don't know RDF; trying this can be a learning-intensive rabbit hole.